# Javascript, viewing [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just started to learn HTML. Doing an `alert()` on one of my variables gives me this result `[object HTMLInputElement]`.

How to get the data, that were  added in text field, where my input type is text?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Say your variable is `myNode`, you can do `myNode.value` to retrieve the value of input elements.

*Chrome Developer Tools* has a *Properties* tab which shows useful DOM attributes.

Also see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement) for a reference.

Comment: I just spent 5+ minutes looking for Firebug, only to find it's been deprecated. Please update your answer

Answer (score 34):

If the element is an [`<input type="text">`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html), you should query the [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text.attrs.value) attribute:

```
alert(element.value);
```

See an example in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZE8sj/).

Also, and seeing you're starting to learn HTML, you might consider using `console.log()` instead of `alert()` for debugging purposes. It doesn't interrupt the execution flow of the script, and you can have a general view of all logs in almost every browser with developer tools (except *that one*, obviously).

And of course, you could consider using a web development tool like [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29), for instance, which is a powerful addon for Firefox that provides a lot of functionalities (debugging javascript code, DOM inspector, real-time DOM/CSS changes, request monitoring ...)

Comment: worked for me when i put the .value after the brackets instead of putting it inside the brackets

Comment: I just spent 5+ minutes looking for Firebug, only to find it's been deprecated. Please update your answer

Answer (score 5):

It's not because you are using alert, it will happen when use document.write() too. This problem generally arises when you name your id or class of any tag as same as any variable which you are using in you javascript code. Try by changing either the javascript variable name or by changing your tag's id/class name.

**My code example:**
**bank.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Transaction Tracker</title>
    <script src="bank.js"></script> 
</head>
    <body>
        <div><button onclick="bitch()">Press me!</button></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript code:**
**bank.js**

```
function bitch(){ amt = 0;
var a = Math.random(); ran = Math.floor(a * 100);
return ran; }

function all(){
amt = amt + bitch(); document.write(amt + "
"); } setInterval(all,2000);
```

---

you can have a look and understand the concept from my code. Here i have used a variable named 'amt' in JS. You just try to run my code. It will work fine but as you put an [id="amt"](without square brackets) (which is a variable name in JS code )for div tag in body of html you will see the same error that you are talking about.
So simple solution is to change either the variable name or the id or class name.

Comment: I haven't realized javascript has this kind of behaviout before, thanks for the explanation. This is exactly what is happened to me.

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
$("input:text").change(function() {
    var value=$("input:text").val();
    alert(value);
});
```

to

```
$("input:text").change(function() {
    var value=$("input[type=text].selector").val();
    alert(value);
});
```

**note:** selector:id,class..

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" id="name">
```

and in javascript

```
var nameVar = document.getElementById("name").value;

alert(nameVar);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" />
<script>
$("input:text").change(function() {
    var value=$("input:text").val();
    alert(value);
});
</script>
```

use .val() to get value of the element (jquery method), $("input:text") this selector to select your input, .change() to bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event.

Answer (score -1):

When you get a value from client make and that a value for example.

```
var current_text = document.getElementById('user_text').value;
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (http.readyState == 4 &&  http.status == 200 ){
                var response = http.responseText;
              document.getElementById('server_response').value = response;
                console.log(response.value);


            }
```

Comment: this is not a very useful answer for the question at hand