# javascript error [object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript, html

i am practicing java script code but having issue while implementing this code.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>  
function f2(){
var a=document.getElementById("a");
var b=document.getElementById("b");
var c=a+b;
document.write(c);
}
</script>  

Enter A:<input id="a" type="text" name="txt1" ><br>
Enter B:<input id="b" type="text" name="txt2" ><br>
<button type="button" onclick="f2()">Sum Here</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When I add two numbers then it shows error like [object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement].

Comment: you need to get the value `c = a.value + b.value;`

Comment: Use `.value` for fetching values. Also note that values will be fetched as string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get total sum from input box values using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540751/how-get-total-sum-from-input-box-values-using-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript, viewing \[object HTMLInputElement\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383765/javascript-viewing-object-htmlinputelement). Have you tried searching?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-how-to-get-value-of-text-input-field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value property of input elements is used to retrieve the value enters in the input. This value will be a string.

Since you want to add numbers, it is better you check if the inputs entered are numbers to avoid unwanted bugs.
There are many ways to check this, one I've used it by adding '+' sign in front of the entered string value, this will convert a number in string to a number and then check for NaN.

here is the fiddle and code 
https://jsfiddle.net/7sgcmfu8/

```
<script>  
function f2(){
var a= +document.getElementById("a").value;
var b= +document.getElementById("b").value;
if(!isNaN(a) && !isNaN(b)){
    document.write(a+b);
}else{
    document.write("enter numbers");
}
}
</script>  

Enter A:<input id="a" type="text" name="txt1" ><br>
Enter B:<input id="b" type="text" name="txt2" ><br>
<button type="button" onclick="f2()">Sum Here</button>
```

Comment: Good solution +1 hit from my side

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<body>
<script>  
function f2(){
var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value);
var c=a+b;
document.write(c);
}
</script>  

Enter A:<input id="a" type="text" name="txt1" ><br>
Enter B:<input id="b" type="text" name="txt2" ><br>
<button type="button" onclick="f2()">Sum Here</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `parseInt()`? OP said "numbers", not "integers".