# Accessing the value of an HTMLSelectElement

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a form where my users select some options from checkboxes and dropdown lists.

The intended outcome is a text that is generated dynamically as the users change their choices.

It works but I keep getting `“[object HTMLSelectElement]”` instead of the value of the selected choice from the dropdown box. How do I get the actual value?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <select name = "birthyear" id = "from" size="3" >
                <option value="1980" >1980</option>
                <option value="1981">1981</option>
                <option value="1982">1982</option>
            </select>
            <select name = "month" id = "month" size="3" >
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
            <select name="day" id="day" size="3" >
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
            <a id="search-btn" href="#">Search</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
let searchButton = document.getElementById("search-btn");
let searchInput = document.getElementById("from");
let searchInput1= document.getElementById("month"); 
let searchInput2 = document.getElementById("day"); 
let summary = document.getElementById("summary");

searchButton.addEventListener("click", findWeatherDetails); 
searchInput.addEventListener("keyup", enterPressed); 

searchInput1.addEventListener("keyup", enterPressed1); 
searchInput2.addEventListener("keyup", enterPressed2); 

function enterPressed(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    findDetails();
  }

}
function enterPressed1(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    findDetails();
  }

}
function enterPressed2(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    findDetails();
  }

}
function findDetails() {
    let searchLink = "https://www.geniecontents.com/fortune/internal/v1/yearly?birthYear="+searchInput+"&targetYear=2019&targetMonth"
    +searchInput1+"&targetDay="+searchInput2;
   httpRequestAsync(searchLink, theResponse);

 }
function theResponse(response) {
  let jsonObject = JSON.parse(response);
  summary.innerHTML = jsonObject.summary;
}


function httpRequestAsync(url, callback)
{
  console.log("hello");
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => { 

        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200)
            callback(httpRequest.responseText); 
    }
    httpRequest.open("GET", url, true); // true for asynchronous 
    httpRequest.send();
}
```

This is the result of the `HTTP GET`

```
GET https://www.geniecontents.com/fortune/internal/v1/yearly?birthYear=[object%20HTMLSelectElement]&targetYear=2019&targetMonth[object%20HTMLSelectElement]&targetDay=[object%20HTMLSelectElement] => 500
```

Comment: To get value from an htmobject use the property value. This question is a duplicate. Use searchinput.value. i will flag this as a duplicate.

Comment: For Example searchInput1.value

Comment: Not every element has a `.value` property, so please be more precise (@KévinBibollet, @EdwinDijasChiwona)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript, viewing \[object HTMLInputElement\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383765/javascript-viewing-object-htmlinputelement)

Comment: @Andreas - You're right, going to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.value` eg. `searchInput1.value`

So your search link in `findDetails()` should be created this way:

```
let searchLink = "https://www.geniecontents.com/fortune/internal/v1/yearly?birthYear=" + 
searchInput.value + 
"&targetYear=2019&targetMonth" + 
searchInput1.value + 
"&targetDay=" + 
searchInput2.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually getting `[HTMLElement Object]` because `document.getElementById` returns the element itself (so a `HTMLElement` object), and the element, when converted to string, is represented in that format.

In order to get the value of your inputs (`<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`), you have to pass through their `value` property.

Check the example below:

```js
// Getting HTMLElement objects here.
const select = document.getElementById('mySelect'),
  textInput = document.getElementById('myInputText'),
  numberInput = document.getElementById('myInputNumber'),
  textarea = document.getElementById('myTextarea');
  
// Getting their value here (XXX.value).
select.addEventListener('change', () => (console.log(select.value)));
textInput.addEventListener('keyup', () => (console.log(textInput.value)));
numberInput.addEventListener('keyup', () => (console.log(numberInput.value)));
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', () => (console.log(textarea.value)));
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="firstOption">1</option>
  <option value="secondOption">2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="myInputText">
<input type="number" id="myInputNumber">

<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
```

---

In your case, you will need to do the following:

```
function findDetails() {
    let searchLink = "https://www.geniecontents.com/fortune/internal/v1/yearly?birthYear=" + searchInput.value + "&targetYear=2019&targetMonth" 
    + searchInput1.value + "&targetDay=" + searchInput2.value;

   httpRequestAsync(searchLink, theResponse);
}
```