# Replace Inputtext with javascript variable returns [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript

I'm strugling to get the following code to work.  I want to replace the input id="timeDiff" value with the value calculated in the function calcTime().

I just can't get it to work and continue to get a value of [object HTMLInputElement] - Any help would be hugely appreciated as I am not well versed in javascript.

Please have a look at the html and javascript below and if you are able to provide a solution please help.

Thanks in advance

```js
(function(d) {

var
 start = d.getElementById('timeStart'),
 stop = d.getElementById('timeStop'),
 diff = d.getElementById('timeDiff');

function textReplace() {
 $("#timeDiff").val(diff);
}
function addEvent(e, event, handler) {
 if (e.addEventListener) e.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
  else e.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
}
function selectHours(e) {
 return new Date(
  '01/01/1971 ' + e.options[e.selectedIndex].value
 ).getTime(); 
}
function calcTime(e) {
 d = new Date(selectHours(stop) - selectHours(start));
 minutes = (diff, d.getUTCHours()*60 + d.getUTCMinutes());
 textReplace(diff, minutes/60);
}
addEvent(start, 'change', calcTime);
addEvent(stop, 'change', calcTime);
})(document);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 lang="en"
 xml:lang="en"
<head>

<meta
 http-equiv="Content-Type"
 content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
/>

<meta
 http-equiv="Content-Language"
 content="en"
/>

<title>
 &lt;SELECT&gt; Time Difference Demo
</title>

</head> <body>

<h1>
 <code>&lt;SELECT&gt;</code> Time Difference Demo
</h1>

<div><!-- since SELECT cannot be a direct child of BODY! -->

<select name="timestart" id="timeStart">
 <option value="00:00:00">12:00 am</option>
 <option value="00:30:00">12:30 am</option>
 <option value="01:00:00">1:00 am</option>
 <option value="01:30:00">1:30 am</option>
 <option value="02:00:00">2:00 am</option>
 <option value="02:30:00">2:30 am</option>
 <option value="03:00:00">3:00 am</option>
 <option value="03:30:00">3:30 am</option>
 <option value="04:00:00">4:00 am</option>
 <option value="04:30:00">4:30 am</option>
 <option value="05:00:00">5:00 am</option>
 <option value="05:30:00">5:30 am</option>
 <option value="06:00:00">6:00 am</option>
 <option value="06:30:00">6:30 am</option>
 <option value="07:00:00">7:00 am</option>
 <option value="07:30:00">7:30 am</option>
 <option value="08:00:00">8:00 am</option>
 <option value="08:30:00">8:30 am</option>
 <option value="09:00:00">9:00 am</option>
 <option value="09:30:00">9:30 am</option>
 <option value="10:00:00">10:00 am</option>
 <option value="10:30:00">10:30 am</option>
 <option value="11:00:00">11:00 am</option>
 <option value="11:30:00">11:30 am</option>
 <option value="12:00:00">12:00 pm</option>
 <option value="12:30:00">12:30 pm</option>
 <option value="13:00:00">1:00 pm</option>
 <option value="13:30:00">1:30 pm</option>
 <option value="14:00:00">2:00 pm</option>
 <option value="14:30:00">2:30 pm</option>
 <option value="15:00:00">3:00 pm</option>
 <option value="15:30:00">3:30 pm</option>
 <option value="16:00:00">4:00 pm</option>
 <option value="16:30:00">4:30 pm</option>
 <option value="17:00:00">5:00 pm</option>
 <option value="17:30:00">5:30 pm</option>
 <option value="18:00:00">6:00 pm</option>
 <option value="18:30:00">6:30 pm</option>
 <option value="19:00:00">7:00 pm</option>
 <option value="19:30:00">7:30 pm</option>
 <option value="20:00:00">8:00 pm</option>
 <option value="20:30:00">8:30 pm</option>
 <option value="21:00:00">9:00 pm</option>
 <option value="21:30:00">9:30 pm</option>
 <option value="22:00:00">10:00 pm</option>
 <option value="22:30:00">10:30 pm</option>
 <option value="23:00:00">11:00 pm</option>
 <option value="23:30:00">11:30 pm</option>
</select>

<select name="timestop" id="timeStop">
 <option value="00:00:00">12:00 am</option>
 <option value="00:30:00">12:30 am</option>
 <option value="01:00:00">1:00 am</option>
 <option value="01:30:00">1:30 am</option>
 <option value="02:00:00">2:00 am</option>
 <option value="02:30:00">2:30 am</option>
 <option value="03:00:00">3:00 am</option>
 <option value="03:30:00">3:30 am</option>
 <option value="04:00:00">4:00 am</option>
 <option value="04:30:00">4:30 am</option>
 <option value="05:00:00">5:00 am</option>
 <option value="05:30:00">5:30 am</option>
 <option value="06:00:00">6:00 am</option>
 <option value="06:30:00">6:30 am</option>
 <option value="07:00:00">7:00 am</option>
 <option value="07:30:00">7:30 am</option>
 <option value="08:00:00">8:00 am</option>
 <option value="08:30:00">8:30 am</option>
 <option value="09:00:00">9:00 am</option>
 <option value="09:30:00">9:30 am</option>
 <option value="10:00:00">10:00 am</option>
 <option value="10:30:00">10:30 am</option>
 <option value="11:00:00">11:00 am</option>
 <option value="11:30:00">11:30 am</option>
 <option value="12:00:00">12:00 pm</option>
 <option value="12:30:00">12:30 pm</option>
 <option value="13:00:00">1:00 pm</option>
 <option value="13:30:00">1:30 pm</option>
 <option value="14:00:00">2:00 pm</option>
 <option value="14:30:00">2:30 pm</option>
 <option value="15:00:00">3:00 pm</option>
 <option value="15:30:00">3:30 pm</option>
 <option value="16:00:00">4:00 pm</option>
 <option value="16:30:00">4:30 pm</option>
 <option value="17:00:00">5:00 pm</option>
 <option value="17:30:00">5:30 pm</option>
 <option value="18:00:00">6:00 pm</option>
 <option value="18:30:00">6:30 pm</option>
 <option value="19:00:00">7:00 pm</option>
 <option value="19:30:00">7:30 pm</option>
 <option value="20:00:00">8:00 pm</option>
 <option value="20:30:00">8:30 pm</option>
 <option value="21:00:00">9:00 pm</option>
 <option value="21:30:00">9:30 pm</option>
 <option value="22:00:00">10:00 pm</option>
 <option value="22:30:00">10:30 pm</option>
 <option value="23:00:00">11:00 pm</option>
 <option value="23:30:00">11:30 pm</option>
</select>
</div>

<p>
 Difference: <input id="timeDiff" value="0">
</p>





  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript, viewing \[object HTMLInputElement\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383765/javascript-viewing-object-htmlinputelement)

Comment: Also, what do you expect `minutes = (diff, d.getUTCHours()*60 + d.getUTCMinutes());` to do? `diff` isn’t used at all here.

Comment: FYI, it hasn't been necessary to put JavaScript inside `<!-- -->` for a long time.

Comment: `textReplace()` doesn't take any parameters, why are you calling it with 2 arguments?

Comment: In `$("#timeDiff").val(diff)` `diff` is the `timeDiff` element. Why are you trying to put an element into its own value?

Answer (score 0):

`textReplace()` needs to take a parameter with the value you want to put in the element.

```
function textReplace(newVal) {
    diff.value = newVal;
}
```

Then you need to pass the calculated value to the function.

```
function calcTime(e) {
    var d = new Date(selectHours(stop) - selectHours(start));
    var minutes = d.getUTCHours()*60 + d.getUTCMinutes();
    textReplace(minutes/60);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are to close to solution

just change your **textReplace()** as below:

```
function textReplace(diff) {
    $("#timeDiff").val(diff);
}
```

and call it like:`textReplace(minutes/60);`

Demo:

```js
(function(d) {

var
 start = d.getElementById('timeStart'),
 stop = d.getElementById('timeStop'),
 diff = d.getElementById('timeDiff');

function textReplace(diff) {
 $("#timeDiff").val(diff);
}
function addEvent(e, event, handler) {
 if (e.addEventListener) e.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
  else e.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
}
function selectHours(e) {
 return new Date(
  '01/01/1971 ' + e.options[e.selectedIndex].value
 ).getTime(); 
}
function calcTime(e) {
 d = new Date(selectHours(stop) - selectHours(start));
 minutes = (diff, d.getUTCHours()*60 + d.getUTCMinutes());
 textReplace(minutes/60);
  console.log(diff+','+minutes/60);
}
//addEvent(start, 'change', calcTime);
addEvent(stop, 'change', calcTime);
})(document);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 lang="en"
 xml:lang="en"
<head>

<meta
 http-equiv="Content-Type"
 content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
/>

<meta
 http-equiv="Content-Language"
 content="en"
/>

<title>
 &lt;SELECT&gt; Time Difference Demo
</title>

</head> <body>

<h1>
 <code>&lt;SELECT&gt;</code> Time Difference Demo
</h1>

<div><!-- since SELECT cannot be a direct child of BODY! -->

<select name="timestart" id="timeStart">
 <option value="00:00:00">12:00 am</option>
 <option value="00:30:00">12:30 am</option>
 <option value="01:00:00">1:00 am</option>
 <option value="01:30:00">1:30 am</option>
 <option value="02:00:00">2:00 am</option>
 <option value="02:30:00">2:30 am</option>
 <option value="03:00:00">3:00 am</option>
 <option value="03:30:00">3:30 am</option>
 <option value="04:00:00">4:00 am</option>
 <option value="04:30:00">4:30 am</option>
 <option value="05:00:00">5:00 am</option>
 <option value="05:30:00">5:30 am</option>
 <option value="06:00:00">6:00 am</option>
 <option value="06:30:00">6:30 am</option>
 <option value="07:00:00">7:00 am</option>
 <option value="07:30:00">7:30 am</option>
 <option value="08:00:00">8:00 am</option>
 <option value="08:30:00">8:30 am</option>
 <option value="09:00:00">9:00 am</option>
 <option value="09:30:00">9:30 am</option>
 <option value="10:00:00">10:00 am</option>
 <option value="10:30:00">10:30 am</option>
 <option value="11:00:00">11:00 am</option>
 <option value="11:30:00">11:30 am</option>
 <option value="12:00:00">12:00 pm</option>
 <option value="12:30:00">12:30 pm</option>
 <option value="13:00:00">1:00 pm</option>
 <option value="13:30:00">1:30 pm</option>
 <option value="14:00:00">2:00 pm</option>
 <option value="14:30:00">2:30 pm</option>
 <option value="15:00:00">3:00 pm</option>
 <option value="15:30:00">3:30 pm</option>
 <option value="16:00:00">4:00 pm</option>
 <option value="16:30:00">4:30 pm</option>
 <option value="17:00:00">5:00 pm</option>
 <option value="17:30:00">5:30 pm</option>
 <option value="18:00:00">6:00 pm</option>
 <option value="18:30:00">6:30 pm</option>
 <option value="19:00:00">7:00 pm</option>
 <option value="19:30:00">7:30 pm</option>
 <option value="20:00:00">8:00 pm</option>
 <option value="20:30:00">8:30 pm</option>
 <option value="21:00:00">9:00 pm</option>
 <option value="21:30:00">9:30 pm</option>
 <option value="22:00:00">10:00 pm</option>
 <option value="22:30:00">10:30 pm</option>
 <option value="23:00:00">11:00 pm</option>
 <option value="23:30:00">11:30 pm</option>
</select>

<select name="timestop" id="timeStop">
 <option value="00:00:00">12:00 am</option>
 <option value="00:30:00">12:30 am</option>
 <option value="01:00:00">1:00 am</option>
 <option value="01:30:00">1:30 am</option>
 <option value="02:00:00">2:00 am</option>
 <option value="02:30:00">2:30 am</option>
 <option value="03:00:00">3:00 am</option>
 <option value="03:30:00">3:30 am</option>
 <option value="04:00:00">4:00 am</option>
 <option value="04:30:00">4:30 am</option>
 <option value="05:00:00">5:00 am</option>
 <option value="05:30:00">5:30 am</option>
 <option value="06:00:00">6:00 am</option>
 <option value="06:30:00">6:30 am</option>
 <option value="07:00:00">7:00 am</option>
 <option value="07:30:00">7:30 am</option>
 <option value="08:00:00">8:00 am</option>
 <option value="08:30:00">8:30 am</option>
 <option value="09:00:00">9:00 am</option>
 <option value="09:30:00">9:30 am</option>
 <option value="10:00:00">10:00 am</option>
 <option value="10:30:00">10:30 am</option>
 <option value="11:00:00">11:00 am</option>
 <option value="11:30:00">11:30 am</option>
 <option value="12:00:00">12:00 pm</option>
 <option value="12:30:00">12:30 pm</option>
 <option value="13:00:00">1:00 pm</option>
 <option value="13:30:00">1:30 pm</option>
 <option value="14:00:00">2:00 pm</option>
 <option value="14:30:00">2:30 pm</option>
 <option value="15:00:00">3:00 pm</option>
 <option value="15:30:00">3:30 pm</option>
 <option value="16:00:00">4:00 pm</option>
 <option value="16:30:00">4:30 pm</option>
 <option value="17:00:00">5:00 pm</option>
 <option value="17:30:00">5:30 pm</option>
 <option value="18:00:00">6:00 pm</option>
 <option value="18:30:00">6:30 pm</option>
 <option value="19:00:00">7:00 pm</option>
 <option value="19:30:00">7:30 pm</option>
 <option value="20:00:00">8:00 pm</option>
 <option value="20:30:00">8:30 pm</option>
 <option value="21:00:00">9:00 pm</option>
 <option value="21:30:00">9:30 pm</option>
 <option value="22:00:00">10:00 pm</option>
 <option value="22:30:00">10:30 pm</option>
 <option value="23:00:00">11:00 pm</option>
 <option value="23:30:00">11:30 pm</option>
</select>
</div>

<p>
 Difference: <input id="timeDiff" value="0">
</p>





  </body>
</html>
```