# Javascript, The <p> element displays [object HTMLInputElement] why does it display this?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure out Object Oriented Programming in javascript and instead of displaying the input on form it displays [object HTMLInputElement]

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let uName = document.getElementById('uName').value;
  info.showInfo();
});
class Information {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  showInfo() {
    var z = document.createElement('p');
    z.innerHTML = this.name;
    document.body.appendChild(z);
  }
}
const info = new Information(uName);
```

```html
<form action="/home.php" method="get"></form>
<label for="fname">First name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="uName" value="value" />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript, viewing \[object HTMLInputElement\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383765/javascript-viewing-object-htmlinputelement)

Comment: @padaleiana i tried but it didnt work.

Comment: `id` of an HTML element creates a global variable referring the ID's owner element. You've declared `uName` inside the event handler function, hence it's not accessible when you're creating the `info` object, and `uName` refers to the input element instead of its value.

Comment: if so how can i access it? i have no idea @Teemu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Teemu said in comment `let uName` is invisible for `const info = new Information(uName);`

Try following code.

```js
uNameElement = document.getElementById('uName');
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const info = new Information(uNameElement.value);
  info.showInfo();
});
class Information {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  showInfo() {
    var z = document.createElement('p');
    z.textContent = this.name;
    document.body.appendChild(z);
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="/home.php" method="get"></form>
<label for="fname">First name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="uName" value="value" />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

UPDATE: `z.innerHTML` replaced by `z.textContent`

Comment: You should be setting the `textContent` property, not the `innerHTML` property!  Otherwise, you're open to injection and invalid JavaScript if reserved characters are used in `name`.