# js is showing [object HTMLButtonElement] onclick?

Tags: javascript

When button clicked JS is showing **[object HTMLButtonElement]** instead of original value.

I want that whenever a button is clicked the value of button is showed.
like when button having value 3 is pressed it will show 3 and not [object HTMLButtonElement]

this is my html file

```
<div class="col-3">
    <button onclick="val(this)" id="n1" value="1" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary "
        style="width:100%" value="1">1</button>
</div>
<div class="col-3">
    <button onclick="val(this)" id="n1" value="2" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary "
        style="width:100%" value="2">2</button>
</div>
```

This is my script.js

```
function val(num) {
  let n = num;
  document.getElementById("ta").innerHTML = n;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript, viewing \[object HTMLInputElement\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383765/javascript-viewing-object-htmlinputelement)

Comment: Button's don't have a `value`. Aside from that, you're passing the button itself into `val()` using `val(this)`.

Comment: When you call `val(this)`, what do you expect `this` to refer to and why?

Comment: @connexo Yes they do. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using `this` inside the onclick html attribute, it will be valued with the html element firing the event so the object being passed to `val()` will be the whole element.

If you need to know the value of the button being clicked, you should retrieve its `value` property

```js
function val(num) {
  let n = num.value;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```css
button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button
  type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary "
  id="n1" value="1" onclick="val(this)">1</button>
<button
  type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary "
  id="n2" value="2" onclick="val(this)">2</button>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using onClick directly on Elements is not really ideal, try using `addEventListener`.

Another advantage of `addEventListener` you can create a delegated event handler, so if you have lots of buttons doing the same thing you can attach one handler to a parent element and all the buttons can be handled.

<strike>Buttons don't store values like INPUT</strike>, but if you want to associate data with buttons try using the `data-` attribute.  eg.. `data-val="1"`, you can then access this using the `dataset` property.

Below is a simple example of using `addEventListener` as a delegated event handler, plus using `data-` attributes on buttons.

> Update: Buttons do have the value attribute, so you could still do
> `e.target.value` too, but I'll leave the `data-` attribute as it's
> pretty handy anyway.. :)

```js
const d = document.querySelector('div');

document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const val = e.target.dataset.val;
  if (val) d.innerText = val;
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30pt;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<button data-val="1">1</button>
<button data-val="2">2</button>
<button data-val="3">3</button>
<button data-val="4">4</button>

<div>
  Click button above.
</div>
```